# Debugging script run in for loop - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Consider the following implementation:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
List<WebElement> countryLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/country/']"));
for (int i = 75; i < countryLinks.size(); i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/country/']")));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement elem = countryLinks.get(i);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //this line will scroll to element.
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," + (elem.getLocation().y - 100) + ");");

    System.out.println("The Country is: " + elem.getText());
    elem.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(countryDetailVerify));
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Above script runs only once, when i = 75. But when I initialize list inside for loop and change for loop to `for(int i=75;i<79;i++)`, then it works correctly.

I want to initialize my list outside for loop, so that I can limit it to size of my list. One way is to make another list with different name. But is that the best option?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the index in the locator with an XPath and loop until then is no more elements:

```js
for(int i = 75; ; i++) {
    List<WebElement> countryLinks = driver.findElements(
        By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, '/country/')])[{0}]".format(i)));

    if (countryLinks.size() == 0)
      break;

    WebElement countryLink = countryLinks.get(0);

    ...
}
```